# Why php code executes 3 times in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am very new to wordpress. I am trying to do the following:

a. I have a very simple html and php based website. I have a signup page which accepts user id and password and then on click of submit button it calls a php file which verifies the userid/password and saves it in the database. THIS WORKS PERFECTLY FINE

b. Now, I trying to move those two pages to wordpress platform. I have installed a php plugin also. Now the problem in wordpress platform is whenever I hit the submit button, in the database 3 duplicate records are getting appended. I have been trying a lot but could not fix this

c. I tried different php plugins but does not work

d. After reading few help documents on the web, I have tried creating my own template page, even that does not work

Any help in this regard will be much appreciated.

---

EDIT

**Form:**

```
<form action="http://xxxxxx.xxx/xxxxxx" method="post">
    Enter User ID:
    <input name="userid" type="text" value="" />Password:
    <input name="password" type="text" value="" />
    Confirm Password:
    <input name="confrimpassword" type="text" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="SIGN UP" />
</form>
```

**Below is the php file:**

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
// Echo session variables that were set on previous page
//echo "Favorite color is ".$_SESSION["favcolor"].".<br>";
//echo "Favorite animal is ".$_SESSION["favanimal"].".";
?>
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","***********","**************");
mysql_select_db("******");
$sql1=mysql_query("select * from login_details where customer_id='$_POST[userid]'");

$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1);
if (!$sql1) {
    echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
    //exit;
}
else {
    echo " inside last else";
    $sql2=mysql_query("INSERT INTO login_details VALUES ('$_POST[userid]','$_POST[password]')");
    echo "Account successfully Created...";
}
mysql_close();
?>
</body>
</HTML>
```

Comment: line 62? in which file?

Comment: in index.php line no 62 is               <?php

Comment: Any more suggestion please?

Comment: Where is your script? What have you done so far? Have you followed the Wordpress developers documents? Have properly added hooks, etc?

Comment: What script do you want? you mean the entire index.php?

Comment: Whatever code is related to your issue

Comment: Please find below the complete code

Comment: Rasclatt did you see the code below

Comment: Couple points on this. If you are doing Wordpress, you will want to use their hooks to add the processing of the page into its load process. Also, Wordpress doesn't use sessions, so that may be a factor in your developing. You should use the Wordpress engine to create your users. Finally, stop using `mysql_` functions, they are deprecated (removed entirely from php7).

Comment: @Rasclatt I simply created two new page in wordpress. In one i pasted the html code and in second the php code. Have i done anything wrong?

Comment: You should look at the wp documentation to get a better idea of what to do